# How does JavaScript turn a bitmask to a boolean expression?

Tags: if-statement, bitmask

I'm confused with how JavaScript turns bitmasks into boolean expressions so you can use them directly in an if-statement. Say, you have two variables, x and y (using Node.JS REPL):

```
> var x = 0x4;

> var y = 0x5;
```

Now you AND them and get

```
> x & y
4
```

Now you compare to booleans:

```
> (x & y) == true
false
> (x & y) == false
false
```

But when you put the bitmask in an if-statement, it works like a charm:

```
> if (x & y) { z = 3; } else { z = 7; }
3
> if (! (x & y)) { z = 3; } else { z = 7; }
7
```

So my question is: Although the expression `x & y` does not compare to a boolean value, it does in an if-statement. What are the comversion rules or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. The `if` part is easier to answer: all values apart from `false`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `undefined` and the empty string `""` are considered to be truthy - `(x & y)` isn't any of those in this case so it's considered to be truthy.

```
> (x & y) == true
false
```

Looking up from EcmaScript specs, the "abstract comparison" or `==` works like this when the the two operands (referred to as `x` and `y` in the document) are of differing types, with the right-hand operand being a boolean:

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

So while most numeric values are truthy, only the value of `true` when casted to a numeric type is equal to `true` in the `==` sense. Testing on my own JavaScript console, I get the result `1` from `+true`, and likewise, `1 == true` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Well, I guess this explains it all. It's kinda awkward, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement in JavaScript is quite easily one of the most debated features on the language, mostly because it does what's called a type coercion. So, it will coerce (x & y), which is a non-zero value, to true which is why you are seeing the result. When you negate it, you also get the result you want. It first coerces ( x & y ) to true, then negates it.

Comment: Yes, but how exactly does this type coercion work? Is it built into the `if` statement or into the `==` operator?

Comment: @alexraasch It's the if statement, if it was the `==` you would have seen that in your tests. The if statement coerces, or more accurately, reduces all expressions to a boolean whether they are meant to be interpreted as such or not. `if(4){ //true }; if('hello') { //true}; if(null){//false}; and so forth which has caused so many headaches to front end developers for years.`

Comment: @rdodev It's not a matter of "whether they are meant to be interpreted as such or not". In JavaScript, as in other dynamically typed languages, objects (and primitives if in the language) have defined truth values which will be used in those contexts expecting a boolean (and you can explicitly evaluate the truth value of a statement by using `Boolean` as a function rather than a constructor). In my opinion, the real issue is that JavaScript does not support customizing the truth value of an object/custom class/etc. (e.g. `object.__nonzero__` in Python 2, `object.__bool__` in Python 3).